# i need to populate math tables in excel using inputbox in vba. "how to populate tables in newly added sheets ?"

Tags: excel, vba

i am using the following code,

```
Sub chk() 

    Dim x As Variant

    Select Case StrPtr(x)
        Case 0
            Exit Sub
        Case Else
            Dim d As Integer
            Dim y As Integer
            Dim ws As Object
            Set ws = Worksheets(1)
            d = InputBox("enter the integer")
            For y = 1 To 10
                ws.Cells(y, 1) = y * d
            Next y
            ActiveSheet.Name = d
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add after:=Worksheets(3)
            Set ws = Nothing
    End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: "i am using the following code"... and?! What is your question? What have you tried?

Comment: @Dhruv Malik What issue are u facing ?

Comment: a new sheet is getting added every time i run the code but i want to generate specific table entered in inputbox in that newly added worksheet.

Comment: you could create the table then use the Data entry form to populate it, or create a UserForm in VBA to get all the data from the user?

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like your table is always being added to Sheet1 rather than the new sheet that you've added? If you want the table to be added to the new sheet, do it like this:

```
Sub chk() 

Dim x As Variant

Select Case StrPtr(x)
    Case 0
        Exit Sub
    Case Else
        Dim d As Integer
        Dim y As Integer
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        d = InputBox("enter the integer")
        Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add After:=Worksheets(3)
        ws.Name = d
        For y = 1 To 10
            ws.Cells(y, 1) = y * d
        Next
        Set ws = Nothing
End Select
```

End Sub